# Can't find `FlaskWebProject` files in Azure set-up

Tags: python, azure, flask

I am trying to run through the creation of a Flask web app in Azure using this instruction page.

[Creating Web apps with Flask in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app/)

In the "Application Overveiw" section, it lists some `FlaskWebProject`files saying.

> Here's an overview of the files you'll find in the initial Git repository

```
\FlaskWebProject\__init__.py
\FlaskWebProject\views.py
\FlaskWebProject\static\content\
\FlaskWebProject\static\fonts\
\FlaskWebProject\static\scripts\
\FlaskWebProject\templates\about.html
\FlaskWebProject\templates\contact.html
\FlaskWebProject\templates\index.html
\FlaskWebProject\templates\layout.html
```

The problem is that I don't get these files when I connect up Azure to a Github repository. I know they exist because my Azure app renders the this default Flask webapp. The files exist in `/wwwroot`.

I am sure that I am missing something obvious here, so if anyone has followed the most recent Flask setup instruction for Azure, and had success, their input would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial GitHub repository is empty, so you need to clone the repository. 
The process is described in the same article you mentioned, but a little later.

Basically:

1) Go to the deployment source and configure the deployment source - for example, local github

2) Go to Settings => Properties. Here you should have Git URL where your files are placed

3) Go to your workstation, and execute

```
git clone https://yourdeploymentusername@todeleteflask.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/todeleteflask.git
```

Enter password.

You should be all set now. Now, if you make change, you may push to the repository and it will arrive on the site.

Comment: It worked! I think the "Continuous deployment using GIT..." article led me astray. They should not link you to that article to find the URL as there are heaps of other tasks listed there. They should just show where to find the URL within that same article. Cheers